# 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages' compatible con 'Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Helpers.Mvc 2.0.20710

Tags: c#, razor, nuget

I created a new project in visual studio 2015, and I was able to program with no problem but then I required to use the microsoft web helper to upload files in to the server and when I looged in to nuget and wanted to install de microsoft.asnet.web.helpers.mvc I got the following error

> Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado de supresión
>   Error     No se encuentra una versión de 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages'
>   compatible con 'Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Helpers.Mvc 2.0.20710
>   restricción: Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages (>= 2.0.0 && < 2.1.0)',
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.es 3.2.3 restricción:
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages (= 3.2.3)'.         0

It seems versions are not compatible, anyone of you know how to correct this? I will apreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: I think it'll be better if you try to get the exception in English, then it will be easier for people to help you.

Comment: Looks like Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Helpers.Mvc restricts Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages to versions between 2 and 2.1. To use it you'll have to install an older version of Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages. You may have to install older version of Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages's depencies in order to do this. You might even be restricted to an older version of .NET.